# Html5 template in Aptana Studio 3 lost, what happened to it?

Tags: html, templates, aptana, setup-project

I'm helping an org update its website. I had created a project in Aptana Studio 3 and at first I focused on cleaning up their folders, which were a mess. I went to make a new html file and I chose an option to use an html5 template. Then I got a little sidetracked making a favicon.

Later, I realized that I had created the project in a folder that I now wanted to get rid of, given all the cleaning and sorting I had done. I hadn't created any files so I just scrapped the project and created another.

That was fraught with error messages that the folder wasn't empty, etc. I restarted Aptana and eventually was able to create the web project. But now when I tried creating an html5 file, there was no html5 template. File > New from Template > HTML only lets me choose Blank File, and that's all I get, a blank file. In fact, all those template choices from Beaver to YAML only have that Blank File option.

I found the template elsewhere so I can create the file using that, BUT, what happened to the templates? Is there a way to reload them?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can manually load them in the bundles folder. I'd download a fresh copy of Aptana, try to grab the default bundles, find the template you're looking for, and copy it over to your current folder.

Here's a bit of a reference:

http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/06/add-or-edit-code-snippets-and-templates-in-aptana-studio-3/

Comment: Oy, download a new copy of Aptana? There must be a better way. I think I did see some brief message about rubles, but not knowing what they were, I ignored it. I guess I lost my rubles, which probably comes right before losing your marbles.

Comment: Haha, well honestly if I were you I wouldn't download Aptana on the same computer since it's typically in an installer package. I would download and install it on a different computer, copy the rubles, and then see if you can either backup and overwrite your current ones or try to find the specific one that has the template you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my computer and the templates magically reappeared!